# Adding chartjs-plugin-datalabels to Chart.js in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, plugins, chart.js, aurelia

Got on-boarded to a new project recently. I've been trying to add the datalabels plugin to my Chart.js feature in Aurelia. I've defined the relevant dependencies in **Aurelia.json** after performing **npm install** on **chartjs-plugin-datalabels**:

```
      {
        "name": "chart",
        "path": "../node_modules/chart.js/dist",
        "main": "Chart.bundle"
      },
      {
        "name": "chartjs-plugin-datalabels",
        "path": "../node_modules/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/dist",
        "main": "chartjs-plugin-datalabels"
      },
```

I also reference the chart.js plugin and the chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js files in the class that uses them.

```
import Chart from 'chart';
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
```

However upon npm start I get a host of errors that express

```
File not found or accessible: ../../chart.js.
```

Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, chart.js folder name convention was different from chart naming as specified in the aurelia.json

https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-deferred/issues/2